# Primeng dropdown is not working in table-angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular7, angular8, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

Tried to get primeng dropdown but not working.I do not know how to do it.If anyone know please help to find a solution.

app.component.html:

```
 <my-tabs (selectedTabClick)="test($event)">
      <my-tab [tabTitle]="'Tab 1'"  id="tab1" #tab1>
          <app-data-table></app-data-table> 
      </my-tab>
      <my-tab tabTitle="Tab 2" id="tab2" #tab2>
      <app-provider-search></app-provider-search>
      </my-tab>
    </my-tabs>
```

data-table.component.html:

```
 <p-column field="missions"  header="Missions">

     <p-dropdown [options]="missons"></p-dropdown>

    </p-column>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-turbo-table-5e5ngc?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Well...you need a missions variable in your .ts file to be able to use "missions" in the p-dropdown

Comment: @Andrew:already there

Comment: From what I saw, you had missions within an array, but not a missions variable directly. that means you can't directly access it as "missions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use and version of primeng compatible with angular verion , primeng has the same version number base of angular verion

template

```
<p-column field="missions"  header="Missions">
  <ng-template let-data="rowData"  pTemplate="body">
   <p-dropdown [options]="data.missions" [(ngModel)]="data.selectedValue"></p-dropdown>
  </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

you need to change primeng option value to be an object of label,value base of primeng acceptable options data

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.interactionHistories.forEach(row => {
      if (row.missions) { 
      row.missions = row.missions.map(value => ({label:value, value}));
      row.selectedValue = row.missions[0];
      }
    });
  }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-turbo-table-5iplmb)

Comment: @NilaVaani did you check the demo everything is working fine

Comment: You have any idea for lazyloading with rxjs state management for this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-turbo-table-1sqfy6?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: is it possible to create a new answer with more information I still don't get what your are asking for it will be very useful for me and you may get help from others 

Comment: Can you answer for this question:61555370